# UTC DateTime to Local and Back gives incorrect time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to be able to convert UTC time to Local Time, add one hour and would like to convert back to UTC for comparison. However, the basic to TimeZone and back to UTC gives incorrect time.

```
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var localTime = utcDateTime.ToZone("Central Time (US & Canada)"); // CORRECT TIME

// INCORRECT when converted back to utc. It should be the same as utcDateTime
var convertedBack = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime);
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What's `ToZone`? I couldn't find it in in `DateTime` documentation. What's the type of `localTime`?

Comment: The whole point of UTC is that you can leave including the Timezone of the users computer to the ToString() function being called. And everytime else you work with a Unambigious value. You **really** do not want to manually handle timezones, ever: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY "That way lies madness".

Comment: Actually got it working with this:             TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
            var convertedBack =TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime, tz);

Comment: @ShaneKm: It is good if it works. Just do mind this old Cite: "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" - https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan

Comment: I need to be able to do it in the code. The reason being I need to take UTC time, convert it back to Users time, set time (add/subtract hours in users time), then convert it back to UTC. In comment I've posted answer that works. thanks

Comment: "add/subtract hours in users time" - you need to be aware that you can end up with ambiguous or skipped local date/time values. It's not really clear what you expect to be different by adding/subtracting values in the user's time zone, but there are lots of gotchas here. (My Noda Time project tries to make those more explicit, but that just means you're forced to think about them up-front. It doesn't remove them.)

Comment: @Christopher: "The whole point of UTC is that you can leave including the Timezone of the users computer to the ToString() function being called." That's really *not* the whole point of UTC. It's got pretty much nothing to do with textual representation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Exactly. It has nothing to do with textual representation. Local Timezone is simply part of the Textual representation of a DateTime value, same way as Date Formats are.

Comment: @Christopher: No, it's really not. Not all date/time values should be represented as instants in time... which is why Noda Time and java.time have separate ZonedDateTime types.

Comment: Local time is bad. don't use it for anything that you plan to use in more than one time zone.

Comment: My rules for DateTimes are: 1) Always Store, Transmit and retrieve the UTC value. Leave display in the Local Timezone to the OS/Framework, they can deal with that mess somewhat reliably. 2) Avoiding doing Store/Transmit/Retreive as strings. 3) If you have to use strings (XML and other serialsation) at least pick a fixed datetime format and string encoding on all endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This works
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var convertedBack =TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime, tz);
```